# What's the term for the debt you have to pay today?

Tags: debt, definition

Say that a company has a debt of 10 million $US

But from that debt, the company has to pay 2 million $US today. The rest of the debt has to be payed next year and later.

Is there a term for the debt that has to be paid today?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you thinking of "due debt"?

Comment: Also maybe “debt maturing today.”

Comment: Yes, that's the term I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Debt due today is an example of a [current liability](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/currentliabilities.asp), although that term also includes liabilities due within one year, and is contrasted with long-term liabilities which are those due in more than one year.

Comment: I can't vote for both answers but I would vote for yours too if I could. Thanks!